# How to read a CSV file using iOS

Tags: ios, csv

I have to develop an iOS application that can read the data from a CSV file hosted on a domain. Is there any standard APIs that can help me to do this? I don't need to download but just read the file because the file will be updated for every two mins.

Comment: you have to make API for that. request the api and can get the data into either json or xml.

Comment: Will i have any issues when i read the data? bcos its CSV format.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I recommend [Dave DeLong](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115730/dave-delong)'s [CHCSVParser](https://github.com/davedelong/CHCSVParser) library for parsing.

Comment: It just means something like 'by the way'. It's a way of adding a note to something if you don't/can't add a footnote - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nota_bene

Comment: NB stands for 'Nota bene' which is Latin for 'Note Well'

Answer (score 0):

You will have to download the file, that is the only way to get it from the remote host to your device. A [CSV File](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) is a text file with data separated by a comma(','). Download the file from the the remote host, read the file line by line, split the line string that was read from the file;

For example:

```
1,2,3,4,1,2,3 ...Line 1
```

Split using ',' as a delimiter and add the split values into an array,  the result will be:

```
array_line_one = {1,2,3,4,1,2,3};
```

Comment: is there any API that can let me access the file from the server?

Comment: Please see http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use, it has info on how to perform HTTP request, if you are downloading from a HTTP server.

Comment: CSV is far more complex than that - what about field that contain commas? What about dealing with quoted fields and unescaping. What about newlines? I would use a library that's tested for all these edge cases rather than roll your own solution.

Comment: @deanWombourne I agree with you comment but it should be at the developers discretion whether or not he/she needs to use a full blown CSV parser library. I mean if the file is relatively simple then using a "own solution" might be better than including a large parsing library of which only the bare minimum will be used.

Comment: Right up until the server returns some data with an errant comma in the data and then the end user comes shouting at the developer because 'his code doesn't work' :) IMHO Better safe than sorry when dealing with input data that's out fo your control.