# How to separate the "comma separated values string" whose values in turn contain commas

Tags: ios, csv

I have a string like this

```
NSString * tempStr = @"abc,def,"ijk,lmn",op,"rst,uvw",xyz";
```

if i separate the values using

```
[tempStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@",\"" withString:@";"];
```

i get output array as

(abc,

def,

"ijk,

lmn",

op,

"rst,

uvw",

xyz)

i want output as an array like

(abc,

def,

ijk,lmn,

op,

rst,uvw,

xyz)

Comment: You need a more intelligent CSV parser than just splitting on ",". The question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8831501/how-to-read-a-csv-file-using-ios has more.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) the parser worked !!